# Terminate jar file process through If commands using batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, jar

Using batch file, Is there any way to terminate a jar file that is running constantly even whenever/if the service has stopped.

In this case, the batch file runs through an "application as service" provider to start the batch as service.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html

Comment: How would one write it to check If the service is stopped, then the batch file will terminate the jar file?